# "Hope the college is nice to me"

Tags: questions

I just wanted to know that "Hope the college is nice to me" is this sentence correct, if yes then does this mean "hope my new college will be good"?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct but it doesn't mean what you wrote in the second sentence.

Comment: I'd like to know if you found this somewhere, or if you're writing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is technically correct but a little off to my ear. A college isn't really a thing that can be nice. You could be talking about the people there - the professors, the students, the dean, the administration - but if that were the case you'd want to be more specific: "hope the professors are nice!"

Note that you *can* say "I hope the college treats me well". This is because "treats you [well]" is an idiom that can be used with inanimate objects and concepts. "How's Monday treating you?" would be a pretty common American English way to ask someone how their day is going on a Monday.

"I hope the college is good" is correct but very vague. If you're trying to express that you hope the whole general experience of going to this college for multiple years will be a positive one, I'd suggest "I hope college goes well for me" or "I hope this is a good college for me".

Answer (score 1):

If you were to drop the article in your sentence then it might mean what you intend it to (depending on what exactly you mean by *"I hope my new college will be good"*). **"Hope college is nice to me."**

With the "the", you are talking about a specific college as an inanimate institution or building. In general, it doesn't make sense to use "the college" in this context. An exception to this might be if you used "the college" to mean "the college authorities", e.g. in a disciplinary context.

Without the "the", it can be used to mean *the experience of going to college*, e.g. "College is great!" = "I enjoy it when I am at college".

The phrase "nice to me" uses *nice* to mean *kind*, so you might want to pick different wording if this isn't what you mean. E.g. "I hope college is good" or "I hope college is fun" or something similar. If you mean that you hope the college is good at teaching (a "good college") then you should say "I hope it's a good college".

Comment: This "the" question is an important distinction, kudos

Comment: RE: _With the "the", you are talking about a specific college as an inanimate institution or building_. I have mixed feelings on that. College – even when written as "the college" – can be more than just a building; it might refer to a four-year experience along with all of the associated interactions with faculty, staff, and students that come with that. If I say, "The college wasn't very good to my daughter," I'm not talking about a building, I'm talking about the experience. Maybe she had repeated run-ins with administrators, or maybe experienced gender bias from students and faculty alike.